# Wix toolset v4 multilanguage

Tags: c#, .net, installation, wix

how can i create multilanguage bundle installer in wix toolset v4? Now i have BootstrapperApplication with LocalizationFile for 1033 code and custom themeFile, but i also need to add another languages that will be chosen for user region (or it also can be some ui with list of languages)

I tried to add another wxl files for different language code, but on build i have error like "  The localization identifier 'Caption' has been duplicated in multiple locations. Please resolve the conflict."

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have all your wix files added in project file like
`

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="*.wxs" />
  <Compile Include="*.wxl" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

`
Removing it from ".wixproj" makes your day ;-).